# How to search for gifs in Twitter API?

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, twitter, python-twitter

I'm using [python-twitter](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter) to build an application that would search for all the tweets including gifs in a given time range for a set of users.

For example, I'd like to get all the gifs from user [@NHLJets](https://twitter.com/NHLJets) during the interval 2017-03-21 -> 2017-03-22.

I know how to get all the rest

`import twitter
api = twitter.Api(...) # The API keys inside the call
print api.GetSearch(raw_query='from=NHLJets&since=2017-03-21&until=2017-03-22')`

Using the Twitter Advanced Search, I can just say `q=gif` and [it works](https://twitter.com/search?l=&q=gif%20from%3Anhljets%20since%3A2017-03-21%20until%3A2017-03-22&src=typd) but for some reason using the `python-twitter`'s `api.GetSearch` it returns an empty list.

`In[34]: api.GetSearch(raw_query='q=gif&from=NHLJets')
Out[34]: []`

I'm willing to change from python2.7 to python3, I'm willing to change Twitter libraries - just curious to know if someone has figured this one out yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Twitter operator you're looking for is `card_name:animated_gif`. The only problem with this operator is that it gives results only 7 days back, so for your query:

```
from:NHLJets since:2017-03-21 until:2017-03-22 card_name:animated_gif
```

you'll get nothing ([try...](https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3ANHLJets%20since%3A2017-03-21%20until%3A2017-03-22%20card_name%3Aanimated_gif&src=typed_query&f=live)). Even if you remove the dates you'll probably get nothing unless they actually posted a gif in the last 7 days.

One way to get around it is to archive gif tweets in real (or close to real) time from a twitter list containing all the accounts of interest. Here is an example of all the tweets containing animated gifs by all of Twitter's official accounts:

```
card_name:animated_gif list:84839422
```

[Try it...](https://twitter.com/search?q=card_name%3Aanimated_gif%20list%3A84839422&src=typed_query&f=live)